# playframework setting custom message for @Required field globally

Tags: java, forms, validation, playframework-2.2

I am looking for help with translating Validation messeges in Play framework 2.2

I have fields that are required:
f.e.

```
@Required(message = "To pole jest wymagane")
public String miesiac;

@Required
public String miejsce;

@Required
public String oddzial;
```

But I would to have this message: "To pole jest wymagane" globally.
How can I achive it?
Should I use conf/messagess.pl file for translation To polish language.
Please give me some help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should use the `conf/messages` file for your default/primary language text and then one or more of the `conf/messages.xx` files for your translations.

The built-in validators are already setup to use the messages files. For example, the `Required` validator will look for the key `error.required` in your messages and display that text. So just define that key in your message files with the text you want to use.

If you wanted to use something other than the default then just specify the key with the message attribute (instead of the full text like in your example).

**Model class**

```
@Required(message = "my.required.message")
public String miesiac;
```

**conf/messages**

```
my.required.message=Hey, you have to type something here.
```

---

Take a look at the documentation for more info:
[Externalising messages and internationalization](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaI18N)

Comment: Hey. Thanks it helps me. Please give me some direction for more custom message like error.int, error.string etc

Comment: @masterdany88 `<Play install dir>\framework\src\play\src\main\resources\messages` seems to have the default list. It looks like it varies somewhat depending on your version but the validation ones are mostly the same. You'd have to look at the source on Github to see exactly what is being used and when.

Comment: any way of changing the color of the message?

Answer (score 4):

All what I found out. Here are my current custom messages in 
conf/messages

```
error.required=This field is required
error.invalid=You need to enter a number
constraint.required=Required*
```

Comment: Any way of changing the color?

Comment: What do You mean? Can You be more specific?

Comment: I want the message to be in red color. How to achieve that? Thank you so much for your quick response

Comment: You can achieve this only with CSS and Scala Form Helpers. It don't have anything to do with this question. I think for that You should open new question.